# How Graphite is getting data?

Tags: graphite

I have installed Graphite as instructed from the Graphite website.
[Graphite](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

It is said in documentation that Graphite doesn't collect data, but can store and render graphs of data on demand. But after configuring localhost, I am able to see data like cache , avgUpdateTime, cpuUsage, errors, memUsage etc.. without installing any (collectD or statsD).

How am I getting this data and which agents are sending these data?

Answer (score 1):

This would be the stats from the carbon deamons one of the component of the solution.

It will only appear on machines that you have installed 'carbon', it is what is listening on TCP/2003 (default).